What is a transliteration of Yahusha or Yeshua?
Google searched difference between translate and transliteration
What is the difference between translate and transliterate?
A translation is a rendering of the meaning of a text into a different language. A transliteration does not render the meaning of the word into the other language, but only represents its sound.
When you transliterate the name of our Saviors name from hebrew to english the name is spelt Yeshua or Yahusha there is no j sound in the original name of our Savior when you pronounce it in Hebrew so why did we give Him a brand new sounding name. In fact there is a celtic god named Esus, also known as Hesus is the personal name of the Celtic-Druids sun savior, closely associated to Jupiter or Zeus.
Should we think a little deeper about the name we speak out loud and in our hearts in reference to our Mighty Savior? I think so.... what do you think about it? Did you know what transliterate meant and the difference between that and translate? Can you see now that the name Jesus is closer to the sun Savior that's closely related to jupiter and zeus???

In the English language the name of the Son of God is Jesus Christ. This is a matter of usage. Language is not what 'experts' suppose it to be or dictate it should be. We make a language ourselves by using it. For centuries, we have called him 'Jesus'. And we shall continue to do so.

Jesus is the Latin transliteration of the Greek Iesous with a Norwegian J in the Geneva Bible that was pronounced as a Y. Regular English speaking people saw the J and pronounced it as such. The name Iesous is a Greek transliteration of the Hebrew name we recognize as Joshua.
While it's often assumed that Jesus' name is actually Yeshua or similar, these are just corruptions of Joshua. Pronounce Joshua with a Y sound and you get Yoshua, or Yeshua.
And the most important thing is that the Septuagint, which was a Greek translation made by Hebrews, transliterates the name we know as Joshua as Iesous. In other words, when they used Greek letters to transliterate the pronunciation of the name we know as Joshua, they did so by giving us Iesous. Ergo, I'm convinced that his name was always Iesous. As opposed to Jesus actually being Yeshua, Yoshua is actually Iesous.
Transliterate the name to Latin, add the Norwegian J, and Iesous becomes Jesus.
